# how to sort Map<String, Map<String, String>>, based on one of the inside map key value in java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have one hashMap in java and want to sort based on one of the key value .
my hashmap likes like below.

```
HashMap= < string, map <string,string> >

key="toUppercase" -> value={ key="column_positions" -> value="4,5" ,
                             key="rule_order" -> value="3" }
key="replace" -> value= { key= "column_positions"-> value= "1,2" ,
                          key= "rule_order"-> value= "1" }
key= "concat" -> value={key= "column_positions"-> value= "6,7"
                        key ="rule_order"-> value= "2" }
```

I want to sort the hashmap based on **rule_order**. could you please help me.

My expected Output for outer hasmap is:

```
HashMap= < string, map <string,string> >

key="replace" -> value= { key= "column_positions"-> value= "1,2" ,
                          key= "rule_order"-> value= "1" }
key= "concat" -> value={key= "column_positions"-> value= "6,7"
                        key ="rule_order"-> value= "2" }
key="toUppercase" -> value={ key="column_positions" -> value="4,5" ,
                             key="rule_order" -> value="3" }
```

Thanks.

Comment: A `HashMap` doesn't have an order. You need to use a list or a `SortedMap`.

Comment: Look at a tree map. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html  You can provide a comparator or use the natural ordering of keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can't sort by the key of the inner map. Moreover, you are not able to sort HashMap.
You can use TreeMap but with `ruleOrder` as key. but in this case, you won't be able to store duplicates. (with same rule order).
You can sort map in runtime :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(en -> en.getValue().get("rule_order")))
     .forEach(this::doWork);
```

Please replce `this::doWork` with neaded code.
Please pay attention that this sample is not null-safe.